# How to put a filename with parenthesis in a variable, that will be used to get the md5sum of?

Tags: bash

I've this file whose name is :
2157-15211-csv (1).csv

obviously, to get it's md5sum, i must escape the parenthesis by quoting and write

md5sum '2157-15211-csv (1).csv' : this works

But the filename comes from another process, that puts it in a variable, so my command is more like

myVar='2157-15211-csv (1).csv';md5sum $myVar

but this fails

I tried this
myVar=CURRENT="'2157-15211-csv (1).csv'"

if I echo $myVar I get '2157-15211-csv (1).csv', but

md5sum $myVar still fails due to the parenthesis

Does anybody knows how to make sure md5sum works with filename that are stored in a variable and contains parenthesis ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not _"make sure md5sum works with..."_ — it's the general bash quoting mechanism and applies to any situation similar to this. You need to double-quote the variable `"$myVar"` (though I prefer the optional braces: `"${myVar}"` so the var can be distinguished even when text runs together)

Comment: Awesome, you saved me. Many thanks

Comment: You may want to look at the Bash manual §3.5.3 [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to see all the variations of `${parameter: ...}` param expansion. Useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the variable so it comes across as a single parameter:

```
md5sum "$myVar"
```

Comment: Variable references should almost always be double-quoted like this; there are a bunch of ways unquoted variable references can cause trouble. BTW, [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is great at pointing out errors like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help !